# How to compare old and previous row and get changed data only in sql using Lag

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table xx_asg with structure :

```
person_id  grade_id effective_start_date effective_end_date
1            null       28-Jan-97             28-Jan-16
1            35         29-Jan-16             31-Dec-4712
6            35         12-Jun-93             31-Jul-93
6            35         01-Aug-93             30-Sep-99
```

I have to find out if there is any change in grade_id by comparing previous row with the next row.
If there is a change then i have to fetch a new column with flag 'Y' 
and also the new grade's effective_start_date. I have tried to create the following query :

```
SELECT  *
From    (
        Select  Person_id,
   Grade_Id,
                LAG(grade_id) OVER (PARTITION BY person_ID ORDER BY effective_start_Date) AS prev_grade_line1,
                Row_Number() Over (Partition By Person_Id Order By Effective_Start_Date Desc) As Rn,
                Effective_Start_Date
                        From    xx_asg
  --WHERE   person_ID = 3
        )
Where   Rn = 1
order by person_id

;
```

But this query is also returning prev_grade_line1 and new grade id as null or the same :

[image]

```
Output should look like :

person_id  grade_id prev_grade_id effective_start_date Flag
1            null       35             29-Jan-97        Y         
6            35         35             NULL             NULL


OR 

ONLY CHAGED ROW 
person_id  grade_id prev_grade_id effective_start_date Flag
1            null       35             29-Jan-97        Y
```

When using :

[image]

This query is returning the frst row as well. That is it treating the previous ggrade of frst row as null. Only 3 changes are there in real but this query is returning four chanegs

[image]

Comment: what should the output look like?

Comment: Thanks for the question. I have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `where` condition to only get the required rows after getting the previous row's value.

```
select t.*, 'Y' flag
from (
select  
Person_id,
Grade_Id,
LAG(grade_id) OVER(PARTITION BY person_ID ORDER BY effective_start_Date) prev_grade_line1,
Effective_Start_Date,
row_Number() Over(Partition By Person_Id Order By Effective_Start_Date) As rn
from xx_asg
) t
where nvl(grade_id,10000000) <> nvl(prev_grade_line1,10000000) 
and rn > 1
```

Comment: there is a possibilty that previous grade is null and then the value changes in the next row right ? will this work in that condition

Comment: see the edit.this would handle null values too..however, make sure that the value used in `nvl` is a value not in the grade column. `null` in the current row and `null` on the previous row would be treated as no-change.

Comment: This is also not working.. i am updating my answer with the screenshot to show you the result

Comment: Thanks @vkp. This is then showing an extra last column. Like the last row : for person id 8 grade_id as 24 and previous_grade_id as null

Comment: i changed the `row number` calculation. it was ordered by effective_start_date desc previously. did you notice that? try the latest one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125197/discussion-between-divya-trehan573-and-vkp).